# Kafka consumer fails serialization when object with same type but different names

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jackson, spring-kafka

There are two projects: Producer and Consumer, both have exactly the same class `PostLikeEvent` with the same fields, but they are located in different packages `com.example.postlikeproducer.PostLikeEvent` and `foo.bar.PostLikeEvent`.

When the producer sends an event, the consumer fails with the exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.postlikeproducer.PostLikeEvent`.

I tried to use `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.use.type.headers=false` property, but then the consumer fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

See `spring.json.type.mapping` property. Essentially like this:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=com.example.postlikeproducer.PostLikeEvent:foo.bar.PostLikeEvent
```

More info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types

Comment: Does that mean that I have to manually map each class? But what happens if I don't know the package name?

Comment: Yes. You have to map each of them. Of course, you can ignore that type info from headers on deserialization (`useTypeHeaders`), but then you need to use a `targetType` on a `JsonDeserializer`. However it is only limited to a single type. So, or you try to rely on a mapping, or you are left on your own with some other custom deserialization mechanism. Not sure, though, what else you would expect: you don't want to map types, but at the same time you want to deserialize anything. How the framework suppose to know the type your payload has to be deserialized to?

Comment: Not sure about the internal implementation of Spring MVC, but in Spring `@RestController`, you can put any type, and annotate it with `@RequestBody` and it will not require any explicit type mapping. 

What is the major difference here? Both approaches can consume and produce JSON, and both rely on Jackson, but one will work without explicit mapping, and the other will fail

Comment: You can do the same here if your `@KafkaListener` comes with a proper type to be inferred by the `JsonDeserializer`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion. What you are saying is indeed done by default with that `JsonMessageConverter`. You probably just do something else you don't show us...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself correctly. My point here is that Spring Kafka should not rely on a specific type header. For example, if Producer will be written in Python, which will send JSON as a string? As I understood from your answer, we will not be able to consume this JSON, because there will be no headers

Comment: I've just gave you a link about `@KafkaListener` and how a `JsonMessageConverter` on the `ListenerContainer` can infer the type to deserialize JSON. Not sure what you need. To compare `@RestController` with something in Spring Kafka you definitely need to use a `@KafkaListener`. What do I miss?

Comment: See this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples/sample-01. It does use the mentioned `JsonMessageConverter` with Spring Boot auto-configuration. The deserializer must be set to regular `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer`

Comment: Deserialization is done by Kafka (before Spring gets control), there is no way to infer the type for a deserializer; so we use the pass-through deserializer (byte array) with a message converter instead, where we **can** infer the type.